# How to assign a downloaded .pfx certificate to only one project in azure devops

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure-devops

I have .pfx certificate that has been downloaded using "Download secure file" task into my `build.sourceDirectory`.Now I want to assign that certificate to only one project, not all projects

Tried a PowerShell script but its throwing below error. Please suggest any other alternates or correct the script if anything wrong

> Cannot find an overload for "Import" and the argument count: "2". At
>   D:\a_temp\88829cbf-115f-4b06-aa8a-c072600792f7.ps1:10 char:1
>   + $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password )
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

```
$pfxpath = '$(Build.SourceDirectory)\cert.pf'

 $password = '{password}'

 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

 $cert = New-Object   
 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2

 $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password )

 $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store 
 -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser

 `$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")`

 $store.Add($cert)

 $store.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might miss an argument for Method `import`. The official documents show that you need to assign a storage flag for import method. For details about [X509KeyStorageFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Import(String, String, X509KeyStorageFlags)
```

For more usage about **Import**, please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.8)